# How interpret $[a,b]\cap\mathbb Q$?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Suppose I have $[a,b]\in\mathbb R$, but then is given
$$
[a,b]\cap\mathbb Q
$$
How should I interpret this intersection?

Isn't this intersection the same as $[a,b]\in \mathbb Q$, i.e. only rational numbers in the interval?

**Update:**

Can I somehow write the intersection in a [more explicit form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)#Basic_definition) (I mean like this: $[a,b]\cap\mathbb Q=\{\dots\}$)?

Comment: $[a,b] \cap \mathbb Q$ is a set, whereas $[a,b] \in \mathbb Q$ is a false statement.

Comment: $[a,b]\in\Bbb Q$ means "$[a,b]$ is an element of the rationals", whereas $[a,b]\cap\Bbb Q$ means "those elements that are in $[a,b]$ and the rationals".

Comment: ... and $[a,b] \in \mathbb R$ is also false.  But presumably $\subset$ is meant.

Comment: A grammatical point of interest: the symbol $\in$ is a **verb**, and therefore the fragment $[a,b]\in\Bbb Q$ is a **sentence**. Conversely, $\cap$ is a **conjunction**, and therefore the fragment $[a,b]\cap\Bbb Q$ is a **noun**.

Answer (score 2):

It is the same as 'only rational numbers in the interval' $[a,b]$.

That said, you're mixing the set operators. The expression $[a,b] \in \mathbb{Q}$ is not correct because $[a,b]$ is not an *element* of $\mathbb{Q}$. $\mathbb{Q}$ is a set of numbers, not a set of sets of numbers (an example of this would be the powerset of $\mathbb{Q}$).

When relating an element to a set we use operators like $\in$; when relating two sets we use operators like $\cup$ or $\cap$.

Answer (score 1):

I would rather first write $[a, b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ as the interval is a subset of the real numbers.

Now, the intersection in question is just the rationals in $[a, b]$. But remember that we define $[a, b]$ as the collection of real numbers $x$ such that $a \leq x \leq b$, so saying $[a, b] \subset \mathbb{Q}$ doesn't make as much sense since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ and we can find irrational numbers in any interval of real numbers.

TL;DR: It's just the rationals in that interval.

Answer (score 1):

$[a,b]$ contains all the real numbers $x$ with $a \leq x \leq b$. $\mathbb{Q}$ is the set of all rational numbers. $[a,b]\cap\mathbb Q$ contains all the rational numbers $q$ with $a \leq q \leq b$.

**Update:** The intersection $A \cap B$ is defined as $A \cap B := \{\,x : x \in A \text{ and } x \in B\,\}$.